# How to import a Gitub project with all dependencies on Android Studio? Specifically cryptocat-android

Tags: android, github, cryptography, controls

I'm new to Android Studio and Version Control and want to know how to import the [cryptocat](https://github.com/cryptocat/cryptocat-android) code correctly. I already imported the code from Github to my Android Studio but it seems that you have to import all the extrenal libraries too. The instructions on their readme.md are not working properly and I dont know what to do :(
Thanks in advance

Comment: Their libraries come as submodule dependencies, which should be covered by the --recursive flag to `git clone` or are explicitly present as jars in the libs subdirectory. What's specifically isn't working for you? Do you get a build error? Please elaborate on what have you tried.

Comment: Thanks, adding the project manually with the recursive flag solved the problem :)

Comment: Here I added it as an answer then so you can accept it, if it worked for you. Cheers :)

Comment: 2 more questions: 
1. There seems to be an error with "config.useBosh". How can I solve this error?
2. What does the yellow box in the right upper corner mean? 
(Migrate Project to Grandle)
http://snag.gy/DaaIU.jpg

Comment: Bosh is http-bind - a technology to use XMPP over HTTP, what's the error that you are getting? Do you mean Gradle? It's the android build system. See http://www.gradle.org/

Comment: I'm getting 3 "bosh-errors". Look this: http://snag.gy/fBGZz.jpg
Yes, I mean Gradle. What is the purpose of this? What can I do with it?
Thank your for your answers :)

Comment: I am out of my depth with respect to the Bosh build errors so I'll hide behind "the rules don't encourage us to have a lengthy conversation in the comments" :) Which it entirely true. I think you'll be better off asking about the Bosh build errors in a separate question, so you'll get more eyes looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you specify the `--recursive` flag with `git clone` to get all the submodules.